# window.load not working if the page has redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have got a strange problem.
I am using `window.open()` to open a new window, and `$(window).load()` to check if the new window has been loaded or not.

The problem is, if the new window has a redirect, the function doesn't work...
Can there be a solution to that?
I tried both `$(window).load()` and `window.onload`... Both give same results.

Any help will be great.

Comment: Is in the same domain?? remember same origin policy

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the jquery method on the new window reference, not on your old window object.

```
var newWindowRef = window.open('url');

$(newWindowRef).load(function(){
    //loaded
});
```